# Uploading a file with in html with filetype constraint

Tags: html, file, csv, file-upload, html-input

I want a user to upload .csv file using file browse of html.
I have used file input type but the user can upload any type of files with that.
What i want is a user can only browse and see .csv file.
How can i do that??
I have read about accept parameter but it is for audio/video/images.
How can i do it with .csv?

```
Upload new Question Bank(.csv):-<input type="file" name="file">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`accept`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#attr-input-accept) attribute:

```
Upload new Question Bank(.csv):-<input type="file" name="file" accept=".csv" >
```